# How can I fix the collapse navbar using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a static website using reactjs so I downloaded a template and I divide it on components using reactjs but the responsive collapse navdar doesn't work anymore and I'm trying to fix it so I tried many solutions but I got nothing.
There are no errors but the code still doesn't work.
can you help me please!
this is the navbar component.

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import '../assets/css/style.css';
import '../assets/css/slick.css';
import '../assets/css/magnific-popup.css';
import '../assets/css/animate.css';
import '../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import '../assets/css/home7fonts.css';
import Logo from '../assets/images/logos/logo-black.png'
function Header()
{
    const [toggleMenu, setToggleMenu] = useState(false)
    const [screenWidth, setScreenWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth)
    const toggleNav = () => {
        setToggleMenu(!toggleMenu)
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        const changeWidth = () => {
            setScreenWidth(window.innerWidth);
        }
        window.addEventListener('resize', changeWidth)
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', changeWidth)
        }
    }, [])
    return (
        <header className="main-header header-seven">
        <div className="header-upper">
            <div className="container-fluid clearfix">
                <div className="header-inner d-flex align-items-center">
                    <div className="logo-outer">
                        <div className="logo"><a href=""><img src={Logo} alt="Logo" title="Logo"></img></a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="nav-outer clearfix d-flex align-items-center">
                        <nav className="main-menu navbar-expand-lg">
                            <div className="navbar-header">
                                <div className="mobile-logo py-15">
                                    <a href="index.html">
                                        <img src={Logo} alt="Logo" title="Logo"></img>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <button onClick={toggleNav} type="button" className="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                                        data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                                    <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div className="navbar-collapse collapse clearfix">
                                {(toggleMenu || screenWidth > 500) && (
                                <ul className="navigation onepage clearfix">
                                    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#services">services</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#faq">FAQs</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#pricing">pricing</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#testimonial">testimonial</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#blog">blog</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                )}
                            </div>
                        </nav>
                        <div className="header-number">
                            <i className="fas fa-phone-alt"></i>
                            <div className="number-content">
                                <span>Tell Us</span>
                                <a href="callto:+1223558656">+12 ) 235 - 586 - 56</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="menu-btn">
                            <a href="#" className="theme-btn style-eight">Start Free Tral
                                <i className="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
            );
}
export default Header;
```

Comment: here is why you added `screenWidth > 500` it's occurring issues.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/ and Copy one collapse navbar you like. Past the code in your function components and change `class` to `className`, etc. 
open your `public` folder at root directory. Find `index.html`. Add bootstrap Css between `<head>`.

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Add Bootstrap JS after `<div id="root">`,

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

then, reload your react project. See it work.